# django: filtering a object-list

Tags: django, url, filtering

I've got a list of objects (properties for rent, in this case) that I am listing, the list needs to be filterable by a handful of criteria (max price, area, n_bedrooms ...) and I figured I could do it like this:

```
(r'^price:(?P<price_min>\d+)?-(?P<price_max>\d+)?/$', property_list)
```

This works, and allows urls like price:300-600/ to do the sensible thing.

However, it becomes unwieldy when there's around half a dozen attributes one could be filtering by, and ideally I would like clean urls (i.e. not including attributes for which we're not currently filtering in the url)

Is there a "standard" way to handle this in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you don't need to reverse these urls you may use optional groups:

urls.py:

```
#the regex might need some work, it's just a concept
(r'^(price(/(?P<price_min>\d+))?(/to/(?P<price_max>\d+))?/$
```

views.py:

```
def view(request,min_price=None,max_price=None):
    ...
```

(django_filters is very nice though)

Comment: Yeah. I considered that, was just wondering if there's a better way. I'll ponder it, thank you for your time !

Answer (score 4):

The right way to do this in django is Alex Gaynor, err [django-filter](http://github.com/alex/django-filter/tree/) by [Alex Gaynor](http://alexgaynor.net/)

It lets you get the filter parameters as http get and filters your queryset on those constraints.

From the docs:

```
import django_filters

class ProductFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'price', 'manufacturer']
```

And then in your view you could do::

```
def product_list(request):
    filterset = ProductFilterSet(request.GET or None)
    return render_to_response('product/product_list.html',
        {'filterset': filterset})
```

Comment: This takes care of the filtering, but (doesn't!) handle the messy part I mentioned above, the keeping-urls-clean by using get-parameters, which means you *do* get the long-and-messy-urls. Or maybe I'm overlooking something ?